# Efficient way of apache active MQ connection pooling

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, connection-pooling

We are using **apache activeMQ** to send messages and we used apache activeMQ connection pooling to send messages.

For this we created `PooledConnectionFactory` object and every time we need to send a message we use the same `PooledConnectionFactory` object to create a new connection object and then session and then message producer. Now once the message is sent, we close the session and connection.

Now while doing **netstate**, we found out that although connection is creating and closing out the count of number of active connection is not decreasing.

Is there any issue with our active MQ connection pooling?
Any pointers will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a pooled connection factory and you call close() on a connection the connection isn't actually closed; it is simply returned to the pool. Therefore the actual network connection remains intact. The whole purpose of the pool is to prevent having to create and close expensive network connections while allowing applications to use a conventional program structure where the connection is "created" and "closed" every time a message is sent and/or consumed. Without using a connection pool such a program structure would be a severe anti-pattern.

Perhaps I've misunderstood, but based on your description I would say there is no problem.

Comment: No @justin Bertram..that is correct.. we implemented the way it is supposed to be and it is working as expected...